# Removing a charged coil from circuit

Tags: capacitor, circuit-analysis, coil, discharge, charge

I have a question:

If I charge a capacitor through a resistor and remove it from the circuit, the capacitor will be charged for a certain amount of time (eventually the voltage across the capacitor will become zero volts.)

What will happen when I do the same with a coil?
I charge the coil with a certain amount of charge (through current.)
What will happen if I remove the coil from the circuit?
It is charged with current so it will not stay in the coil I think, or does it?

Comment: To sustain the energy stored in an inductor, you need to short the terminals.

Answer (score 3):

An inductor will actually stay charged for a time after you disconnect it.

You have built up a magnetic field around the inductor.  When you stop feeding it current, the magnetic field will change.  This should cause a current to flow, but the electric circuit is open leaving no path for the current.

The voltage rises, trying to keep the current flowing.  This goes on until the magnetic field is gone.

The voltage can get much higher than the voltage you used in the first place.

That is the basic core of boost converters.  They run a current through an inductor, then open the circuit.  The voltage goes up, and you can pick it off when it is high enough to suit your needs.

---

One of the worst electrical "zaps" I ever got was from a large inductor.

I had a speaker that used a big coil and a piece of soft iron instead of a permanent magnet.

I switched off the power to the magnet coil, and touched a bare connection from it a little later.

The voltage was pretty high.  Just a jolt, but it hurt like hell.

Comment: The coil you touched was still energised by coupling from the other coil, right?

Comment: Nope.  It was a **big** coil.

Comment: If the inductor was still charged you would've seen a big spark when you disconnected it, which would've discharged it.

Answer (score 1):

When you disconnect the capacitor you do so by opening the circuit.  It stays charged for a time proportional to the capacitance times the leakage resistance.

Inductors are weird (to us).  To effectively disconnect an inductor from a circuit, you do so by *shorting* it's terminals.  It will stay charged for a time proportional to the inductance *divided* by the coil's resistance (or essentially forever if it happens to be a superconducting coil).

If you disconnect an inductor by opening the circuit then it'll force as much voltage as needs be to cross the gap you've created in the circuit until something breaks down or until it finds some capacitance to charge up.  This is the basic principle behind the Kettering (points & coil) ignition system for cars, and the reason you need flyback diodes on relay drivers.